# Show timezones using google maps api v3

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I want to show timezones on the map I created using google maps api v3.
I want to show something like this --> http://24timezones.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using a deprecated API, you can use API v2 in combination with sample code that is easily found with a Google search.

Otherwise, I think you will need to find a data source that will give you the timezones in some format (perhaps KML?), and draw them on to the map perhaps using `Polyline` objects.